# Another boolean modifier problem

Tags: modifiers

[image]

Blender 2.78. i have a model that as best i can tell has all of these for every object on every layer:

- all normals correct
- no doubles
- no internal faces
- no loose geometry
- fully manifold

the three cutouts for objects are to be applied using boolean ops to carve away affected geometry; lift guide, glue plugs, and lift nuts. the first two apply properly. when the boolean op for lift nuts is added, the window clip disappears.

i've browsed page after page of boolean op problems here and elsewhere and gone over my model intently. i don't think i've missed something so then i'm left considering that i'm naive to some aspect of this.

Comment: You using n-gons extensively. I would always expect problems with trying to use booleans with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blender's Boolean Modifier sometimes seems to work completely random. This is mostly the case when you have objects that are a little more complex than basic shapes like cubes, cylinders and the like.

In this cases it's helpful to show the modifier exactly what you want by creating overlapping parts. Just pull the lower vertices of the lift nuts down a little so they clearly overlap the window clip.

[image: fixing mesh]

Comment: awesome, this was perfect. i'll have to remember this as i haven't encountered this problem before

Answer (score 1):

From my experience it seams, that when using boolean you should always make ends of hole cutting mesh, stick out of the mesh, that is being cut. So in this instance you have to go to edit mod and raise up top vertices of bolts, above surface of window clip and lower bottom vertices of bolts below surface of window clip. This will solve the problem.
p.s.
By bolts I mean cutouts, lift nuts and cutouts, glue plugs

Comment: ah, a very helpful hint to have. i'll mentally bookmark this to check when my boolean fails next time. thank you